# Is there a app that will work with Ubuntu and itunes?

Tags: 14.04, itunes

Im wondering if there is a program that will work on Ubuntu 14.4 that is compatible with iTunes and the iTunes store?
lotts484

Answer (score 0):

There is no native Ubuntu application that provides access to the iTunes Store. But you can install iTunes with [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.*